# Changing text between <p> by Pushing Button

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having trouble having a collection of javascript functions change some text on a webpage I'm working on.  The page initial shows the status of three items (amount due, current balance, beginning balance), and the objective is to deduct the amount due from the previous balance to get the current balance and then to show each of the three updated items (amount due, current balance, previous balance).

Here is the JavaScript and HTML:

```js
var amountDue = "Amount Due = $0.00"
var currentBalance = "Current Balance = $950.00"
var beginningBalance = "Beginning Balance = $972.69"

var p = document.getElementById('amount_due');
btn.onclick = function(){
    p.textContent = amountDue;
};

var p = document.getElementById('current_balance');
btn.onclick = function(){
    p.textContent = currentBalance;
};

var p = document.getElementById('beginning_balance');
btn.onclick = function(){
    p.textContent = beginningBalance;
};
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FE7C00">
<h1 style=font-family:Arial;text-left;size:14pt;
color:#00FF00;>
Account Details
</h1>
<p id="amount_due">Amount Due = $22.69</p>
<p id="current_balance">Current Balance = $972.69</p>
<p id="beginning_balance">Beginning Balance = $972.69<br></p>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Pay Amount Due?" />
<br>
<br>
<br>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Crif Dogs</td>
    <td>December 5, 2015</td>
    <td>$4.56</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tony's Pizza</td>
    <td>December 6, 2015</td>
    <td>$10.57</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
 <td>Xian's Famous Foods</td>
 <td>December 7, 2015</td>
 <td>$7.56</td>
 </tr>
</table> 
<script src="java.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
</body>
```

Right now nothing is happening when I click the button.   Any idea how I can have javascript change all of the `p` contents to the new information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting the `btn.onclick` function and the `p` variable's value.

Renaming the "p" variables and doing all content changing in one `onclick` function gets the job done.

```js
var amountDue = "Amount Due = $0.00"
var currentBalance = "Current Balance = $950.00"
var beginningBalance = "Beginning Balance = $999.69"

var amountDueP = document.getElementById('amount_due');
var currentBalanceP = document.getElementById('current_balance');
var beginningBalanceP = document.getElementById('beginning_balance');
btn.onclick = function() {
    amountDueP .textContent = amountDue;
    currentBalanceP .textContent = currentBalance;
    beginningBalanceP .textContent = beginningBalance;
};
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FE7C00">
<h1 style=font-family:Arial;text-left;size:14pt;
color:#00FF00;>
Account Details
</h1>
<p id="amount_due">Amount Due = $22.69</p>
<p id="current_balance">Current Balance = $972.69</p>
<p id="beginning_balance">Beginning Balance = $972.69<br></p>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Pay Amount Due?" />
<br>
<br>
<br>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Crif Dogs</td>
    <td>December 5, 2015</td>
    <td>$4.56</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tony's Pizza</td>
    <td>December 6, 2015</td>
    <td>$10.57</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
 <td>Xian's Famous Foods</td>
 <td>December 7, 2015</td>
 <td>$7.56</td>
 </tr>
</table> 
<script src="java.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help with this one.  I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Have modified the js.Here is the snippet

```
var amountDue = "Amount Due = $0.00"
var currentBalance = "Current Balance = $950.00"
var beginningBalance = "Beginning Balance = $999.69"
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.addEventListener('click',function(){
  var p1 = document.getElementById('amount_due');
  var p2 = document.getElementById('current_balance');
  var p3 = document.getElementById('beginning_balance');
  p1.innerHTML=amountDue;
  p2.innerHTML=currentBalance;
  p3.innerHTML=beginningBalance
  },false);
```

**EDIT**

Replace `innerHTML` with `textContent`

```
var amountDue = "Amount Due = $0.00"
var currentBalance = "Current Balance = $950.00"
var beginningBalance = "Beginning Balance = $999.69"
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.addEventListener('click',function(){
  var p1 = document.getElementById('amount_due');
  var p2 = document.getElementById('current_balance');
  var p3 = document.getElementById('beginning_balance');
  p1.textContent =amountDue;
  p2.textContent =currentBalance;
  p3.textContent =beginningBalance
  },false);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gebd8LLt/2/)

Hope this will be useful

Comment: Thank you for the help with my question.